Check whether two JSON schemas are semantically the same
We automatically generate a JSON schema from our Java model on every build of our application, and automatically publish the schema on specific CI/CD pipeline runs. We need the schema to be versioned, and schema version is different from application version.
Schema version is manually maintained in our application code; whenever we change our model, we need to manually increase schema version defined in a constant. Eventually, each schema version will be published to a website as our-schema-x.y.json.
To avoid accidentally changing the Java model (and thus schema) without updating schema version, we'd like to compare the previously published schema with the newly generated schema, and fail the build if they are semantically different.
We only care about structural schema changes, like allowed properties being added or removed, changes in allowed property (enum) values, ... Non-structural changes like updated property descriptions are allowed, in which case we'd update the already published schema version.
Question is how to best perform such comparison, based on deserializing the schemas into Jackson JsonNode instances:

Default Jackson-based comparison ignores property order, so we don't need to worry about this
Default Jackson-based comparison takes array order into account. I guess for enum arrays we should explicitly ignore array order, what about other JSON schema fields that take array values?
We can remove description fields before comparison. Are there any other JSON schema fields that could potentially change without affecting the JSON structure described by the schema?
Any other considerations/specific JSON schema properties that require special attention?


Depends which JSON Schema draft is used. $schema could indicate keyword behavior differences. The best case scenario is to use validation in testing with a known passing instance from the previous schema. It really depends how constrained your schemas are, though. Also, not all language behaviors can be directly translated to JSON Schema, particularly around inheritance models used in Java. JSON Schema doesn't have an inheritance model. This is probably a better conversation in the JSON Schema slack.  https://join.slack.com/t/json-schema/shared_invite/zt-1rptj13ch-ZygpGVq7jUxQYpct0vwsGQ

Defining a set of test instances to check any newly generated JSON Schema could work. JSONBuddy includes a JSON Schema testing tool. You can define test data and compare the results automatically. This is described in more detail here https://www.json-buddy.com/json-schema-tester.htm You can also run the testing tool from the command-line for your CI/CD integration (Windows platform).

we do something similar: we auto-generate a simplified schema for our data model (omitting all extra attributes like descriptions) and check that into our git repository. whenever the data model gets changed in a significant way, the auto-generated schema changes as well, i.e., a simple equality check between both schema versions is sufficient to detect the need for a new schema version in your case.

Since you are already auto-generating your schema based on application code, I assume you can steer what level of details goes into the schema.
One possible approach could be to generate two variants of a single schema version: a complete one (with descriptions, validation hints, etc.) and a simplified one (focusing on the structure alone).
After any change, a new simplified schema will get generated. If it is identical to the existing simplified schema, the schema version can remain as-is. Otherwise, the schema version needs to be increased and the simplified reference schema can be replaced with the new one.

Which attributes are safe to ignore and which aren't is hard to answer generically and also depends on the schema draft version you're targeting.

At the least, structural attributes like oneOf/anyOf/allOf/not/if/then/else should be considered,
as well as the obvious type, properties, items, definitions/$defs, $ref attributes,
possibly more advanced attributes such as dependencies, dependentSchemas, $anchor, $recursiveAnchor, $recursiveRef
and related ones like additionalProperties, unevaluatedProperties, patternProperties, unevaluatedItems, prefixItems, contains, propertyNames etc.
whether validations should be included can be debated, e.g., const, enum, required, dependentRequired, minimum, maxLength, minProperties, maxItems, uniqueItems, ...
You already stated description, title, $comment and such can be ignored. Some of the above validation attributes probably too.

